# Update query for database

Tags: sql, database, syntax, dbm

What's wrong with my SQL update? I'm trying to update records with the upcoming value for status records with the value as missed & due_date BETWEEN 2020-08-01 AND 2020-12-31.

Where is the Syntax error?

```
UPDATE
  records
SET
  status = upcoming,
WHERE
  status = ‘ missed ’ & due_date BETWEEN 2020 -08 -01
  AND  2020 -12 -31 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be written as:

```
UPDATE records
   SET status = 'upcoming'
   WHERE status = 'missed' AND
         due_date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND  '2020-12-31';
```

Notes:

- Strings should be in single quotes.
- Dates should be in single quotes.
- SQL uses `AND` not `&` for boolean AND.